# D3D line draw split into triangles - it almost works, but need a hint

Tags: c++, line, direct3d, hlsl

I'm trying to write a general D3D11 line draw with variable width.  It works but only when the line is about 45 degrees.  Then it 'breaks up' as shown in the pic.  Ignore the model and the triangle.

[image: Screenshot]

First, the calls to attempt to draw the lines, pretty basic:

```
g_UILineShader.SetActive();
for (float x = 0; x < 800; x = x + 10)
{
    g_UILineShader.DrawUILine(pd3dDevice, x, 0, 800-x, 600, 3, XMFLOAT4(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
}
g_UILineShader.Render(pd3dDevice);
```

and ultimately, the render code for the triangle list:

```
HRESULT Render(ID3D11Device * pd3dDevice)
{
    auto devcon = DXUTGetD3D11DeviceContext();

    // Copy all of the vertices in the array to the vertex buffer

    D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE ms;
    devcon->Map(_pVertexBuffer, NULL, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, NULL, &ms);      // map the buffer
    memcpy(ms.pData, &_vertices[0], _vertices.size() * sizeof(UILineVertex));   // copy the data
    devcon->Unmap(_pVertexBuffer, NULL);                                        // unmap the buffer

    // Set the vertex buffer on the device context
    UINT stride = sizeof(UILineVertex);
    UINT offset = 0;
    ID3D11Buffer * pBuffer = _pVertexBuffer;
    devcon->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &pBuffer, &stride, &offset);

    // Select which primtive type we are using
    devcon->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D10_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);

    // Draw the vertex buffer to the back buffer
    devcon->Draw(_vertices.size(), 0);

    // Once rendered we can discard all of the vertex data
    _vertices.clear();
    return S_OK;
}
```

Can anyone spot a bug or fundamental misunderstanding?  If there's a better way to draw lines in screen space that allow for different angles and thicknesses, I'd rather not reinvent the wheel but haven't come across one.

The shader seems fine and merely divides the screen space coords by the screen size to get it into the -1,+1 space in both the X and Y dimensions.  I don't think normals would matter, or could they?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone runs into something vaguely similar, it turned out to be my rasterizer state; the cull mode was the opposite of the way I was winding my triangles.  "Yay" for the VS2013 graphics debugger.